# What does this regular expression part add?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I came across this regular expression in the jQuery source code:

```
...
rmozilla = /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))?/,
...
```

I was wondering why it was rather complicated. I'm especially interested in the reason behind the second part:

```
(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))?
```

I did some research but I could not figure out what this part of the regular expression adds.

```
(?:)      to match but not capture
.*?       any amount of any character
 rv:      something literal
([\w.]+)  one or more word characters or a dot
?         appear 0 or 1 time
```

Particularly, that last `?` doesn't make much sense to me. The whole second part matches if there is or is not a substring as defined by that second part. With some trial and error the regular expression does not seem to differ from just:

```
/(mozilla)/
```

Could someone shed some light on what the second part of the regular expression is supposed to do? What does it constrain; what string fails that passes `/(mozilla)/` or the other way round?

Comment: I suspect it's to work around some browsers faking Mozilla by putting it in their user-agent string.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Was this part of a jQuery plugin? If so, which one? Knowing where this code appears might shed some light onto /why/ the author wanted this particular pattern, and therefore what the pattern is doing.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. What does the regexp add to prevent fakers?

Comment: @normalocity: In fact it's part of jQuery itself: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js, line 66.

Comment: For those who don't want to count lines: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L45 .

Comment: @pimvdb it might have at some point been further checked (beyond a simple match) to see what was in the user-agent string. For example, the IE UA would match just `/mozilla/`, so some further verification might have been required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two regexes would match the same strings, but would store different information in their capturing groups.

for the string: `mozilla asdf rv:sadf`

```
/(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))?/
$0 = 'mozilla asdf rv:sadf'
$1 = 'mozilla'
$2 = 'sadf'

/(mozilla)/
$0 = 'mozilla'
$1 = 'mozilla'
$2 = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd like to clarify the difference between:

```
.*? - non-greedy match
.* - greedy match
```

The non-greedy will match the smallest number of bytes possible (given the rest of the search string), and the greedy one will match the most.

Given the string:

```
mozilla some text here rv:abc xyz
```

The regex will return both 'mozilla' and 'abc'. But if the 'rv:' doesn't exist, the regex will still return 'mozilla'.

Comment: True, but they're usually referred to as "non-greedy" and "greedy", respectively.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I now notice that this answer might be a bit out of scope. I will still leave it for further information, but if you think it is too much out of scope, just comment and I will remove it.

---

@arnaud is right, it is to get the version. [Here is the code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L829) where the expressions is used:

```
uaMatch: function( ua ) {
    ua = ua.toLowerCase();

    var match = rwebkit.exec( ua ) ||
                ropera.exec( ua ) ||
                rmsie.exec( ua ) ||
                ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && rmozilla.exec( ua ) ||
                [];

    return { browser: match[1] || "", version: match[2] || "0" };
},
```

You can see that the function returns the version if found and `0` if not. This might be necessary for some browsers or is just provided as additional information for developers.

The function is called [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L870):

```
browserMatch = jQuery.uaMatch( userAgent );
if ( browserMatch.browser ) {
    jQuery.browser[ browserMatch.browser ] = true;
    jQuery.browser.version = browserMatch.version;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `([\w.]+)` inside of `(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))` is capturing, so maybe this regex was used to get the revision number in the past (however it seems that currently jquery only checks if the regex matches).

Answer (score 0):

(pat) is a pattern delimiter for matching an full contained pattern.
*(?:pat)* is the negation of above, just like the Character set bracket [^ ] is the negation of [ ]. In javascript the negation occurs with *!*
. matches any character, * is a quantifier of matches, and can in newer Regex Engines also written as {0,} (but those three additional characters may likely result in an earlier death of your keyboard!)
? redundant match quantifier: may match zero or one time
rv: .... literal rv

another submatch, may match zero or one time within the parent match
([\w.]+))?
[\w.]... character set, with escapted w "\w": any alphanumerical character, aka [a-zA-Z0-9_] followed by a literal dot, and per match quantifier +, may occur one or more times

To reverse engineer the meaning of the pattern match: just evaluate from left on right, in a text editor and substitute the letters by random literals that come to mind and for which each sub-expression matches.
Then take a step back and ponder what the regex might have been for.

Comment: Please take advantage of SO's [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) feature; as it is now, your answer is almost unreadable.

Comment: The answer also contains several errors, to wit: **1.** `(pat)` is a capturing group; **2.** `(?:pat)` is a *non-capturing* group, not a negative lookahead as you seem to be implying (that would be `(?!pat)`); **3.** `*` is equivalent to `{0,}` in almost all regex flavors--age has nothing to do with it; **4.** that first `?` makes the preceding `*` reluctant (not redundant); **5.** `[\w.]` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_.]` (i.e., it matches a word character *or a dot*, not *followed by a dot*, as you said.